# Sending an express instance to http.createServer

Tags: node.js, express

I see from Node.js [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) that `http.createServer` takes a `requestListener` argument. From what I read, `requestListener` is a function automatically added to `request` event.

I would like to know how you can pass an instance of `express` to `http.createServer` like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
```

How can `app` be a requestListener? Is it a function? I think I am not sure about what is returned by `express()`.

Comment: Don't forget that in javascript every function is also an object (which can have methods and properties) so something doesn't have to be only a function.  It can be both a function and an object with other methods and properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `express()` [returns a function](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.10.1/lib/express.js#L26-38).  That function takes the `req` and `res` arguments that the http `request` event passes in.

Express also adds numerous properties and methods to the function (remember that JavaScript functions are also objects), and those are what you think of as the Express API.